# Transmission 2.94 on Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't work

Tags: networking, vpn, downloads, bittorrent, transmission

Transmission after a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't download anything. Tried many suggestions in Ask Ubuntu; like 'picking a random port' in the network options and also trying to operate it with a VPN. All to no avail.

I've noticed the same behavior in Ubuntu 18.04, which made me switch to another Torrent client which worked without any issues.

I love Transmission and I hope I can make it work. Any suggestions?

Comment: 2.49?  or do you mean 2.94?  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=transmission

Comment: Has Transmission not been allowed through your Firewall? `ufw` or `firewalld` for example?

Comment: It's 2.94 sorry for the mistake, I'll edit the question

Comment: How can I allow Transmission through Firewall? and why isn't allowed by default?